# '90s kids movie about a game robot attacking people

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a movie that was set in the US, and all the characters (including the robot) spoke English.

I can't recall the exact plot, but mostly it was about an innocent game robot that shoots small objects for fun and becomes dangerous, because its AI made a wrongful choice about 'winning the game'. The robot starts to arm itself with more dangerous objects (not sure but knives and stuff) and starts to attack people.

It was overall supposed to be fun and adventure movie for kids. Color movie, and probably made in 80~90's.

There is a recurring scene when the robot detects an aggressor, it scans and loudly announces "enemy one, enemy one". The robot was somehow looking similar to Wall-E, and had a saucer-like head part.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're looking for [Evolver](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112993/combined) from 1995.

> A popular virtual-reality video game gets ported to real life, and Kyle, one of the best Evolver players in the US, gets the opportunity to try playing against a little robot version of the arcade game. However, Evolver is programmed to win at all costs, and the match between Kyle and Evolver gradually becomes a frantic struggle for survival.

The robot replaces its harmless foam balls with knives and considers Kyle ***'Enemy 1'***. The trailer:

Comment: I thought of this film as well (and see this answer is accepted), but I don't recall it necessarily being a "fun and adventure movie for kids". :p

Comment: Yes PawnInGameOfLife, I also remember I was slightly scared when I watched it as a kid :)